# Undefined error using PHP to export MySQL table to CSV

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am using this snippet I found from an old post to download a MySQL table to CSV. It downloads the CSV fine, but I always get an 'undefined' error in with no other details that displays in my browser window. The CSV file does not contain any data about the error mixed in with the text. Any help with what my error is would be much appreciated.

I have tried testing my SQL statement, and that works fine.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employees");
if (!$result) die('Couldn\'t fetch records');
$num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);
$headers = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) {
    $headers[] = mysql_field_name($result , $i);
}
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
if ($fp && $result) {
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="employeelist.csv"');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');
    fputcsv($fp, $headers);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
    }
    die();
}
```

Comment: So all that echos in the browser is "undefined"? Not "undefined index" or "undefined field", etc.?

Comment: It was not clear to me where this error appears 'undefined'. He appears in executing the PHP script? Or the file generated? If the PHP, it does not return the error line?

Comment: It does not give the normal PHP error box. It simply echos undefined. Nothing else in the browser and none of that ends up in the CSV, which normally would happen if PHP was returning the error in its formatted box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the initial question, but I guess it was unrelated to my code somewhat. I think I found my problem.

The page was being linked from JQuery mobile, and even though it as a standard HTML page. Because of the page transitions with JQuery mobile, I think that is causing the message. Sorry for not considering that. I did not consider that as a pertinent detail. Thanks for all your suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your 'die' condition to this:

```
if (!$result) die( echo mysql_error() );
```

That will at least provide you with a little information to go on.  You probably have more to troubleshoot after that, but you gotta start somewhere, and that's the beginning.

Step 2 for troubleshooting:
use `print_r( $headers )` right after the first `for` loop

Step 3 for troubleshooting:
start printing debugging output within the `while` loop if neither of the first steps reveal anything useful. For example, use something like `print_r( array_values( $row ) )` inside of that loop.

My original post should have more clearly stated that it was the first step in troubleshooting because you haven't provided any information about what you have done in your attempts to troubleshoot other than run the code.

Comment: If the problem was the connection to the database, return the error `'Couldn\'t fetch records'` to him. I think your suggestion has nothing to do with the reported problem.

Comment: You may be right, which is why I stated "that's the beginning."  From that point, I would suggest using `print_r( $headers )` right after the first `for` loop, then start printing debugging output within the `while` loop as step 3 if neither of the first steps reveal anything useful. Again, that was only suggested as a first step in troubleshooting, which I think I stated pretty clearly.

Comment: I tried that and I still do not get any other error message returned except undefined. On first try, it gives me the error, and then if I refresh or try to view source then the CSV opens up in Excel where the data is fine.

Comment: Actually this is your answer only a good practice, not forward solution to the problem of the questioner. I suggest that in this case you supplement your answer by giving all possible suggestions for solution. No offense, I'm just suggesting to better quality of their posts.

Comment: Understood. So I maybe should have just left a comment asking, "What did you try instead of making a suggestion on where to start troubleshooting because the original post does not contain any information about what troubleshooting has been done. @user1098504 : Have you tried the second and third troubleshooting steps in my comments above?